# How is implemented the hamiltonian simulation of Hermitian operator multiplied by projection

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, projection-operator

The article ["Quantum Topological Data Analysis with Linear Depth and Exponential Speedup" (Ubaru et al)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.02811) discusses the implementation of the Hamiltonian $\Delta_\Gamma$, named the combinatorial Laplacian, which depends on a certain simplicial complex $\Gamma$. The Hamiltonian is defined as $\Delta_\Gamma = P_\Gamma B P_\Gamma B P_\Gamma$, with $B$ as the sum of Pauli strings and $P_\Gamma$ as the projection. $P_\Gamma |s\rangle = |s\rangle \iff |s\rangle \in \Gamma$. It is not difficult to create an oracle that checks the condition of the projector, $O_\Gamma |s\rangle|0\rangle = \begin{cases}|s\rangle |1 \rangle, & s\in \Gamma \\ |s\rangle|0\rangle, & s \not\in \Gamma\end{cases}$; in contrast, the decomposition of $P$ in Pauli string is nontrivial.

While it is clear how to perform the Hamiltonian simulation of $B$ alone, it is unclear to me how the projection is performed. Can you sketch the quantum circuit for such an implementation or provide a reference for such a construction?